# how to hide tool tip in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have tooltip for each table row to show edit options. I make it visible using this code:

```
function popupFunction(p) {
    var popup = document.getElementById("sp" + p);
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

It's working well. But now the problem is how to hide it if I click any other places?

Here is my html:

```
<div class='popup' id='eds'>
  <i class='fa fa-ellipsis-v' id =" + values.items[i].id + " onclick='popupFunction(this.id)'></i> 
  <span class='popuptext' id =sp" + values.items[i].id + ">
    <div onclick='edit(this.id)' id =ed" + values.items[i].id + ">Edit</div>
    <br/>
    <div onclick='deleteFunction(this.id)' id =de" + values.items[i].id + ">Delete</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: please add plain/final html instead of generation logic, so we'll be able to add more detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

if `show` class makes an element to be rendred as tooltip, then removing it, should hide it.

```
document.getElementById(some_id).classList.remove("show")
```

should do the trick, i believe.